# Why is this AWS call picking only the first element of the array (PHP/AWS)

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Using the AWS PHP SDK to play around with S3 for the first time

```
$res = $s3->list_objects($bucket);
var_dump($res);
```

Shows me that I have a `Contents` array with 4 elements in it

However `var_dump($res->body->Contents)` yields only one XMLObject instead of a php array with for elements like it should.

What's going on?

Comment: Can you include in your question each of:
var_dump($res);
var_dump($res->body->Contents);

Answer (score 1):

The S3 library read the XML response and returns an XML/DOM object. It cannot be printed like a normal array. You are advised to iterate over it like it says in the PHP manual.

However, for quick tests you can cheat.

```
var_dump(json_decode(json_encode($xml)));
```

Personally, I would see if a JSON response can be returned - they are generally smaller, faster to parse, and easier to browse than DOMNode's or DOMLists.